# How to open any URL inside an app with flutter by tapping on image or card?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Well, I am new to **Flutter** and trying to make a simple **business card** kind of app.
I am unable to figure out how to open any link inside an App by tapping on the Icons of this app:-
Here is my code written in Dart(I have removed some part of the code but kept the required one's)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            //To align everything which is inside the container
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 60,
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/myself.jpg'),
              ), //image
              Text('Manish',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  )), //Name
              Text(
                'FLUTTER DEVELOPER',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                  fontSize: 13.0,
                  color: Colors.indigo[900],
                  letterSpacing: 1.8,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ), //Flutter developer
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                ),
              ), //Height
              Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                //To resize this container
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 1.0,
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                ),
                //There's no padding property in "Card" but if you are using "Container" then you can use
                //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                      7.0,
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.phone,
                        color: Colors.teal[500],
                        size: 30.0,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        '+91 9876543211',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ), //Phone Number
              Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                //To resize this container and give spaces for all the container
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 10.0,
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                ),
                //There's no padding property in "Card" but if you are using "Container" then you can use
                //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.email,
                        color: Colors.teal[500],
                        size: 30.0,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        'xfgbxgfbxfg@gmail.com',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ), //Email
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(13.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 69.5,
                        height: 69.5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('images/LinkedInIcon.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                          //shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ), //LinkedIn
                  Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(13.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 69,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('images/GitHubIcon.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                          //shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ), //Github
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**Can anyone help me with this?**

Answer (score 0):

Try the plugin below, it is a flutter plugin for launching a URL in the mobile platform. Supports iOS and Android.

[Url Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't see a place where you used the plugin in your code. @ManishShah